# Nginx ssl_session_cache difference between shared:SSL and shared:MozSSL?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

When setting `ssl_session_cache` in `Nginx` I often see examples set it as one of the two options:

`ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;` or `ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;`

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: [It's an arbitrary name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a name. It can be any string.